# Quotient vs Ratio vs Fraction vs Rational

Tags: rational-numbers

I can't seem to differentiate between a Quotient and a Ratio and a Fraction and a Rational. From what I know a rational is a number like $2/3$ or $5.4/7$  whereas quotient, ratio and fraction all are just three names for one same thing $1+x/1-x^3$ , and that is just same as rational number except that a variable is used instead of a number. Am I correct ?

Comment: See [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7320/19689) answer on a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly.

A **quotient** is used for the *result* of dividing an integer into another. It is also used in similar or analogous senses -- anywhere one reduces an object by another, the result of this reduction is called a quotient -- e.g., the set of equivalence classes of a set with respect to an equivalence relation.

The words **ratio** and **fraction** are more alike, although ratio carries a more analytic flavour while fraction sounds algebraic -- at any rate the two stand for any *expressions* of the forms $A:B,A/B$ and $AB^{-1},$ without regard to whatever meaning they could have. In short, these words (fraction is the more frequently used these days) refer to a merely *formal* expression.

Finally, a **rational number,** or a fraction of integers, is simply a ratio or fraction where $A$ and $B$ are both integers, with $B\ne0,$ of course.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest of these to define is a *rational number*. It's a number that can be written as a fraction with integer numerator and denominator, even if it doesn't visibly appear that way. So these are all rational numbers (in fact, the same rational number):
$$
\frac{3}{2} , \ 1.5, \ 1 + \frac{1}{2},\  \frac{1}{2/3}, \ \frac{3\pi}{2\pi} \ .
$$

A *quotient* is an expression formed by dividing one thing by another. So these are quotients:
$$
\frac{3}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}, \ \frac{3+ \pi}{2}, \frac{x+ 5}{x^2} \ .
$$

Sometimes you think of a quotient expression as the number it represents, when it happens to represent a number. Sometimes that number is rational, sometimes it isn't.

A *ratio* is a little more subtle. It usually occurs in an application of some kind. For example, if the ratio of boys to girls in a math class is $2:3$ then $2/5$ of the class are boys. If you are travelling at $20$ miles per hour then the ratio of distance covered to hours spent is $20:1$.

Comment: Your definition of *rational number* is spot on; however, *quotient* is wrong -- it is not the expression (or appearance) that's the quotient -- that's what's called a *fraction* -- but the *result* or product of *any* operation similar to integer division.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac AB$$ is a *ratio*, whatever $A$ and $B$ denote. *Fraction* is a quasi synonym, that also conveys the graphical representation with a division bar.

A *quotient* is the result of a division, especially when there can be a remainder (as in integer and polynomial divisions).

A *rational* (number)  is any number that can be expressed as the ratio of two integers.

---

**Addendum:**

A *rational fraction* is the ratio of two polynomials.