# Do "the ratio of A to B" and "A:B" always mean A/B as a fraction?

Tags: definition, ratio

### Question

- Do the expressions "the ratio of A to B" and "A:B" **always** mean the same as $\frac{A}{B}$ (i.e. A divided by B) and not $\frac{B}{A}$?

I found several sources that use "the ratio of A to B" as $\frac{A}{B}$ and one source that uses "A:B" as $\frac{A}{B}$. These sources listed below.

### Sources that use "the ratio of A to B" as $\frac{A}{B}$

- [An article on Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/trigonometry-right-triangles/reciprocal-trig-ratios/a/reciprocal-trig-ratios) :

> The cosecant is the reciprocal of the sine. It is **the ratio of the hypotenuse to the side opposite a given angle** in a right triangle.
> $$csc(A) = \frac{hypotenuse}{opposite}$$

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi :

> Greek letter π to represent **the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter** was by Welsh mathematician William Jones in 1706.

- [An answer for a question "ratio expressions which are correct" on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/265982) :

> The a to b ratio is 1:2.

> The ratio of a to b is 0.5

### Sources that use "A:B" as $\frac{A}{B}$

- [An answer for a question "ratio expressions which are correct" on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/265982) :

> The a:b ratio is 0.5.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874862/quotient-vs-ratio-vs-fraction-vs-rational),

Comment: @RobertIsrael, here's another related post:  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-explain-the-difference-between-the-fraction-a-b-and-the-ratio-a-b   Is there a consensus on whether there is a widely adopted convention on whether $C=A/B$ can be expressed in English as "$C$ is the ratio of $A$ to $B$"?  It doesn't seem as eloquent to write, "$C$ is the result of dividing $A$ by $B$" or "$C$ is the fraction $A$ over $B$".