# Is there a definition of the words: Quotient, Fractions and Ratio?

Tags: terminology, definition, fractions, ratio

I'm curious, do we have a definition of quotient, fraction and ratio?

The Wikipedia page is very unclear. To be honest I've used those words interchangeably to mean any expression of the form $$\frac{A}{B}, \ \ A:B, \ \ AB^{-1}$$ where $A$ and $B$ are whatever, integers, real numbers, polynomials etc.

I was wondering if I'm actually correct is using these terms interchangeably? There is [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2874862/552998) but the people who have answered it don't seem to agree.

Comment: My take is that "quotient" is used when there is explicit division, while "ratio" is the only one (among the three words) that can relate more than two quantities.  From MESE (no clear consensus in the answers either): [Using terminology for the different concepts of rational number](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/4289/372) and [How to explain the difference between the fraction a / b and the ratio a : b?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/7281/372).

Comment: @ryang Well, now that I've read up all those articles and many more, there does seem to not be a general agreement. However what do you mean by "explicit division"?

Comment: I mean when the division operation is being discussed (or at least being emphasised).